# Empty Image is uploadded

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios, nativescript

Image Upload to wordpress is uploading empty image

I am working on a mobile application consumes wordpress API. My application uses Nativescript-Vue Framework. I need to upload multiple images to wordpress using remote WP-API.

```
        var data=[];
        const params = new FormData();
        //params.append('file', this.value);

         this.product.images.forEach(i => {
           params.append('file',i.src);
           console.log(i.src);
         });

        const axiosInstance = axios.create({
          baseURL: 'https://mah.ttawor.com/wp-json/wp/v2/',
          timeout: 5000,
          headers: {
            Authorization: this.auth_token,
            'content_type':'multipart/form-data' ,
            'Content-Disposition':`attachment; filename="product.jpg"`
          },
        });

        if(this.product.images.length === 0) return;


        axiosInstance.post('media',params)
          .then(response => {
            //console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
    }
```

Unfortunately, Word Press receives an empty image. Any solution, i have tried nativescript-background-http.That does not work either, it has a lot of problems with oauth with wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, {N} doesn't support multi-part data upload out of the box. You may follow on the [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59) on Github for further updates.

It's recommended workaround is to use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/) plugin meanwhile.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-background-http
```

Comment: But i have an authentication problem with jwt using nativescript-background-http. Do you have such an example?

Comment: You can pass headers easily, just refer the readme file of plugin.